# Should the truth values of all sentences $Q$ equivalent to the fixed sentence $P$ be the same?

Tags: logic

This might be silly, but I'd like to be sure about it. Suppose I'm making an application of a kind of logic, say mathematical logic on certain objects. And then there is one sentence: $P \to Q$.

- Suppose $P \to Q$ is true, should every sentence equivalent$[1]$ to $P \to Q$ also be true? My guess is *yes*.
- Is it possible that for certain objects (not restricted to mathematical objects), we can have $P \to Q$ true but $¬P \to ¬Q$ false? I remember of having read two comments in a post on Math Overflow, the second one was a reply to the first:

  1. The contrapositive is a mathematicians best friend.
  2. Then anyone whose contrapositive is not a best friend is not a mathematician.

I don't know if this could be seen as $P\to Q$ and $¬ P\to ¬Q$, but It's the only thing I remember.

- What would happen if the behavior I asked in the second $\bullet $ could happen? Is it inconsistent? Is that logic (mathematical logic) not adequate for that class of objects?

I apologize if I'm being too vague. But this is still a little bit confusing to me.

$[1]:$ Same truth table.

Comment: $P \to Q$ is equivalent to $\lnot Q \to \lnot P$ (its *contrapositive*) but **not** to $\lnot P \to \lnot Q$.

Comment: In general, two formulae of propositional logic are equivalent when they are both *true* or both *false* for the same row of the truth table. With this def, you can check the assertion of the above comment writing the t-t for the three formuale above.

Comment: How are you defining "truth"? You defined equivalence, but not truthfulness.